# Replacing individual characters in a StringBuffer

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace the individual 'a' character in 'Amazon' by using the **.replace** method in Java.

I know how to do this with Strings, but when I use the code below with StringBuffers, I get an output of 'Amaazon' instead.

Does anyone know of a way to replace the individual characters in a StringBuffer?

```
    public class Hello {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
    StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer("Amazon");
    String str = new String("Rainforest");
    int a = str.indexOf('o',2);
    StringBuffer str2 = str1.replace(2, 2, "a");
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(str2);
    } 
}
```

Managed to find the right way to do it through the answer, so I thought I'd post my corrected code:

```
public class Hello {

public static void main(String argv[]) {
StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer("Amazon");
String str = new String("Rainforest");
int a = str.indexOf('o',2);
StringBuffer str2 = str1.replace(0, 1, "b");
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(str2);
}
```

}

To get the output of "bmazon"

Thanks to the answerer!

Comment: You almost never actually want to use `StringBuffer`, use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Why is that, @LouisWasserman?

Comment: @GrahamJohn: Because it says so in its doc.  "Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to StringBuffer as it will be faster under most implementations."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an off-by-one error.  The first two parameters to `replace(...)` are the starting index of the substring to replace, *inclusive*, and the ending of the substring to replace, *exclusive*.  By using the same value for both, you are in effect "replacing" the nothing between indexes 1 and 2.  This inclusive/exclusive way of expressing a range is extremely common.

Comment: Can you also include the corrected code in this answer?

Comment: Have posted my corrected code in the question, thank you for the answer!